# How to install VISP from ubuntu packages?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

I want to install [visp](https://visp.inria.fr/install/) on ubuntu `20.04`.
It is mentioned that:

> To install them, simply type:
> `sudo apt-get install libvisp-dev libvisp-doc visp-images-data`

But I'm getting an error:

```
E: Package 'libvisp-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libvisp-doc
```

Can you please tell me how can I install this package properly? thanks.

Comment: [The packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libvisp-dev) are in `universe`, so enable `universe` using `sudo add-apt-repository universe` or other methods shown in the dupe and try again

Comment: @mrur `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`

Comment: Ah I see, you're using 20.04. It seems these packages are only available for 22.04 and newer.